# How to run LTSpice from terminal in Linux?

Tags: ltspice, linux, python

I've installed LTspiceXVII on my linux machine and it is running fine, but I cannot get it to run a simulation using the terminal. This is a necessity for me since I want to automate a circuit via python.

Here is what I've run:

```
$ cd ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/LTC/LTspiceXVII
$ wine ./XVIIx64.exe -Run -b examples/Educational/opamp.asc
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
wine: Read access denied for device L"\\??\\Z:\\", FS volume label and serial are not available.
002d:err:menubuilder:Process_Link unable to load L"C:\\users\\alkubuntu\\Recent\\Draft1.asc.lnk"
002d:err:menubuilder:wWinMain failed to build menu item for L"C:\\users\\alkubuntu\\Recent\\Draft1.asc.lnk"
```

Comment: Did you get a `.raw` file? It looks like the problem only refers to the inability to find a schematic from the recent items list. Maybe the drive was not mounted? Because you ran it in batch mode it probably simulated silently, but threw that error (which can be ignored, if that's the case).

Comment: So I have a virtualbox with windows 10, and I ran the exact same circuit and it worked.